# After populating the object I want to use the fields to get data for a other object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have populated my object Contract when using the debugger I can see it has populated the object. But later when I want to use the objects fields but it is undefined. I do not understand why this is the case. Here is the line in question where contract is undefined.

```
console.log("test id contract client" + this.contract.contractId);
```

And Here is my full code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Client } from '../../models/client';
import { Contract } from '../../models/Contract';
import { ClientService } from '../../services/client.service';
import { ContractService } from '../../services/contract.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contract-customer',
  templateUrl: './contract-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contract-customer.component.css']
})
export class ContractCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  public contractNumber: string;
  public client: Client;
  public contract: Contract;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private clientService: ClientService, private contractService: ContractService) { }


  ngOnInit():void  {
    // First get the contract id from the current route.
    const url = window.location.href;
    var parts = url.split('/', 6);

    this.contractNumber = parts[4];

    console.log("Contract Id form url : " + this.contractNumber);

    this.GetContractClient();

  }


  GetContract(id: string) {
    this.contractService.getContract(Number(id)).subscribe(result => {
      this.contract = result;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  GetContractClient() {
    this.GetContract(this.contractNumber);

    console.log("test id contract client" + this.contract.contractId);

    this.clientService.getClient(this.contract.contractId).subscribe(result => {
      this.client = result;
    }, error => {
      console.log('something wrong here!!!')
        console.log(error)
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output of the log statement? What is the exact error message? What line is the error coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ngOnInit()` you call `this.GetContractClient()`

THEN

In `GetContractClient` you call `this.GetContract(this.contractNumber)`

The code in `GetContract` is asynchronous code. This means that it does not execute immediately. For example, if I said "I'm making a cup of coffee" it does not happen instantly. It takes a while for the kettle to boil. Same with asynchronous code. You haven't provided information about what your service is doing but I am guessing it makes an HTTP call to your server. This takes time. This asynchronous code starts to execute but the rest of the code does not wait for it to finish execution. It continues. Hence, the code:

```
console.log("test id contract client" + this.contract.contractId);
```

Executes next.

However, the subscribe block here has not yet been executed. IT ONLY EXECUTES WHEN THE HTTP CALL COMPLETES.

```
this.contractService.getContract(Number(id)).subscribe(result => {
  // IMPORTANT: THIS LINE ONLY EXECUTES WHEN THE HTTP CALL COMPLETES
  this.contract = result;
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

So the code `this.contract = result` has not yet been executed which is why contract is undefined on this line:

```
console.log("test id contract client" + this.contract.contractId);
```

To fix it do this:

```
this.contractService.getContract(Number(id)).subscribe(result => {
  // IMPORTANT: THIS LINE ONLY EXECUTES WHEN THE HTTP CALL COMPLETES
  this.contract = result;
  console.log("test id contract client" + this.contract.contractId);
}, error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Hope that helps you to understand asynchronous code.

Comment: The console.log is there for me to test that contract works outside of the contractService. Is there a way to wait for HTTP CALL TO COMPLETE? In this case I can work around it but I belive that in some case I might need the contract to work outside the method GetContract.

Comment: Theres 4 solutions I know of ... (1) put all code that you want to execute after the HTTP completes inside the relevant subscribe block OR (2) call the functions that must be executed after the HTTP call completes inside the subscribe block OR (3) use an rxjs pipe to do stuff after the http call completes (stuff in an rxjs pipe is executed before stuff in the subscribe block but after the http call completes) OR (4) switch to using promises instead of observables and use async await ... you would need to Google how to do these last 2 approaches

Comment: note when using the async await pattern, code execution literally waits for the async code to finish before executing the next line, however, generally people do not use promises coz observables afford more flexibility, they are just harder to get your head around initially!